# The Enter Key does not close a Form if the Focus is on a Button that is not the AcceptButton

Tags: c#, winforms, dialogresult, acceptbutton

I have a modal Form with three Buttons, A B and C.

In addition, I have two Buttons: `OK` and `Cancel`. The `OK` Button's `DialogResult` property is set to `DialogResult.OK` and the `Cancel` Button `DialogResult.Cancel`.
The Form's `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` properties are set to these Buttons.

Currently, the Form is closed when I press the `ESC` key but if I click the `ENTER` key when one of the other Buttons (A,B,C) is the Active Control, the Form is not closed. How can I overcome this?

I have two options:

1. Enter will always close the form (select the focused button and then close it),
2. The first Enter key press will select the focused button and a second `ENTER` press will close the Form. The problem is that maybe Button `A` was selected but the user can go over Button `B` or `C` using the arrow keys.

I can't set a `DialogResult.OK` to the other Buttons, because - in that case - a normal click will also close the Form and I have no way to detect if the event was called because of a Click event or the `ENTER` key...

Comment: Show us the code that you've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to activate the Default button - the Button that is set as the Form's [AcceptButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton) - when another Button has the Focus, but not another Control, as a TextBox, that may want to accept the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you can override [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey) (since pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key doesn't raise the `KeyDown` event and the `Click` event is raised before the `KeyUp` event), verify whether the [ActiveControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol) is of type Button (or other type of Controls you want to behave the same way) and set the `ActiveControl` to your `AcceptButton`.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is *transferred* to the `AcceptButton` and the Dialog is Closed, returning `DialogResult.OK` (since you have already set the Button's `DialogResult` value):

**Note**: this assuming that the Container Control is the same.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter) {
        if (ActiveControl.GetType() == typeof(Button) &&
            ActiveControl != AcceptButton) {
            ActiveControl = AcceptButton as Button;
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

In case you just want to change the `ActiveControl`, setting the Focus to the `AcceptButton` - so the User needs to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice to confirm, return `true` after you have changed the `ActiveControl`, to signal that the input has been handled:

```
// [...]
if (keyData == Keys.Enter) {
    if (...) {
        ActiveControl = AcceptButton as Button;
        return true;
    }
}
return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
```