# How to capture enter key press event in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

Enter Key Down event can’t be captured when the property of KeyPreview was set to true, neither if I have a button on the Form, my qustion can I chapture the enter key even if I have focus on the button.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtSLC.png) as in the picture I have a form with nine buttons in it, the focus is on one of the buttons.

I have tried, KeyPreview and set it to true, PreviewKeyDown and they are both didn't work.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318164/enter-key-press-in-c-sharp

Comment: Didn't work, the keyUp worked tho, didn't know why the keydown won't. I can do it but throught the previewKeyDown but for all the buttons which is not a dynamic way.

Comment: Override `ProcessCmdKey` in your Form. A few notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093298/7444103)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a good practice to capture `global keys` (There may be another application doing that) yet you can capture it by using the below code snippet:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterHotKey(Handle, refToHotKey, 0, (int)Keys.Enter);
    }
    
    const int refToHotKey = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == refToHotKey)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Key");
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mohi for your response. That's not what I had in mind, I edited the question, can you please read it again.